# Spring data n+1 problem and filtering on big entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot with hibernate/spring data project that has a performance issue, an entity with a lot of OneToMany relationships. Using hibernate can I fetch multiple entries and all its children in one query? The query is also filter based on various fields (which change according to what the user selects) thus writing a native script or hql will be difficult to implement and maintain.

I tried using EntityGraph but I ran in the Cartesian Product issue.

I know that I can use joi fetch, but there are a lot of filters for this entity and thus it will render it difficult to write.

Can you help me find a simpler solution to fix this performance issue?

Best regard

Comment: Hello, you could try to split your entity to the smallest ones, in your case many relationships means not well-structured database architecture, probably, you not fit 3 normal forms requirements.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot split the entity in smaller ones, If I split this entity I need to refactor whole app...

Comment: So.. Unfortunately, you need to refactor whole the app, because normal architecture implies your entities have in dependant only DAO layer, otherwise, architecture is not scalable and every time you change something in entities (that can happen often, because business requirements change from period to period) you will need to change the whole app

Answer (score 0):

This approach (fetching multiple OneToMany in one query) created a ton of problem for me in the past (behind the scenes it does cartesian product before creating the entity for you).

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/

Vlad is the real deal. I followed his advice and "To avoid a Cartesian Product, you can fetch at most one association at a time. So, instead of executing a single JPQL query that fetches two associations."

If you execute 2 jpql queries in the same transaction (you may need a @Transactional annotation in your method to keep the transaction boundaries open between the 2 jpql queries) this will "combine" the results of the 2 queries in a single entity / collection with the best performance :)

See also here https://www.baeldung.com/java-hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception#ideal-solution-using-multiple-queries (paragraph 8 has the suggest solution just like Vlad's).

I hope it helped :)